# How can I test if the user is a fan of my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, fan-page

How can I test if a user is a fan of my facebook page without requesting any additional permission, like you see it on [link of unrelated facebook spam application removed].

Comment: Please specify the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php example:

```
<?php

$signedRequestObject = parse_signed_request( $_POST["signed_request"],YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET );

if ($signedRequestObject["page"]){
    // this means this signed_request was generated on a page
    if ($signedRequestObject["page"]["liked"]){
        // the page was liked
    }
}


//used functions
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  $sig = $this->base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode($this->base64_url_decode($payload), true);
  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    echo  'Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 : ';
    return false;
  }
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    echo = 'Bad Signed JSON signature!';
    return false;
  }
  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\Hosting\7564746\html\facebook\b\fan.php on line 17

Comment: remove $this references ... so $this->base64_url_decode($encoded_sig); becomes base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);